# GIt push from local to local

Tags: git, git-push

I am trying to add a second local repo on my local machine. So I created a directory, made a `git init` there and then I ran : `git remote add new_repo /path/.git`

Then from my local repo, I ran `git push -u mybranch`, knowing it is my working branch from where I push, then  I get the error :

```
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
```

How can I success push my stuffs on the second repo ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to tell it *where* to push. `git push -u new_repo mybranch` will push `mybranch` locally to `mybranch` on `new_repo` (and set up tracking so that in the future, `git push` will default to pushing `mybranch` to `new_repo`).

Answer (score 1):

Git just doesn’t know *what* to push – tell it:

```
git push new_repo mybranch:mybranch
```

Answer (score 0):

push from one local repo to another local repo
Here push from the dev branch of the current local repo2 to the master branch of local repo1
Note: **the master branch of the repo1 should not be in checked-out state**, or the push will fail, you can add a new branch and checkout when testing

```
cd /path/to/repo2.git/
git push /path/to/repo1.git/ dev:master
```